Could chaos theory and butterfly theory prove that time only exists in the present?
I am sorry if this were to sound dumb but, chaos theory is about reconizing patterns and the universe itself can only repeat it self
, would that mean that time only exist in the present cause if time exists in the past future and present cause if it did time would not repeat itself as time has already happend but if not than time must exist in the present cause the only thing that time could do was repeat itself.thia could lead to the 4th dimension being disproved as the 4th dimention is all stae and time.

Chaos theory is about studying systems that are highly sensitive to initial conditions, leading to unpredictable long-term behavior despite having deterministic underlying equations. It does not necessarily imply the universe can only repeat itself a finite number of times. Modern physics still treats time as a legitimate fourth dimension perpendicular to the three spatial ones. The idea of time existing only in the present is a metaphysical stance, not a conclusion from chaos theory or cosmological models themselves.

I know it was not a concluision i was just saying could it hint towards

It was not a concluison more of a theory.
